# Change row number when dragging formula to the right

Tags: excel

I hope you are all well.

I have a list of 10 names in column A on Sheet1:

```
A1 = David
A2 = Jack
A3 = Peter
...

How can I do so I get the names in A1, B1, C1... on Sheet2?

When I type `=Sheet1!A1 in A1 on Sheet2 then I drag the formula to the right I am getting =Sheet1!B1 instead of =Sheet1!A2.`
```

Thanks

Comment: Without formulae, try transpose ie copy: paste.special: transpose

Comment: Simply use this formula in Sheet2, `=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$10,COLUMN(A1))` well using a formula will be dynamic however if you don't want dynamic then you can follow as mentioned above ^^^^ by @SolarMike as well

Comment: If you are using a recent version of Excel then you might also want to look at the TRANSPOSE function. You might not need to drag it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You may try any one of the following ways as per your Excel Version,**

**Formula used in cell A1 and Fill Across --> Works For All Excel Users**

```
=INDEX(Blad1!$A$1:$A$10,COLUMN(A1))
```

**Formula used in cell A2 no need to fill across since it will spill and applicable to only Excel 2021 & O365 users**

```
=INDEX(Blad1!$A$1:$A$10,SEQUENCE(,10))
```

[image: ROW_NUMBER_TO_RIGHT]

Comment: Thank you very much, then if for example you have on Sheet1! A1= 1 , A2 = 2; then on Sheet2! you have A1 = 5 and you want to get A1 + Sheet!1 A1 = 5 + 1 = 6 in B1 and A1 + Sheet!1 A2 = 5 + 2 = 7. Would you use this formula? =$A$1+INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$2,COLUMN(A1))